# XPath query with out child nodes

Tags: xpath

Is there any way that I can get a node with out the its children using Xpath? For example,

```
<parent id="10">
     <child1 id="12"/>
     <child2 id="13">
        <innerchild id="14"/>
     </child2>
</parent>
```

I just need an xpath query to return something like this `<Parent id="10"/>` only

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it once you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's the entire document, simply use `/parent`. If the `parent` with that `id` can be at any level, use `//parent[@id='10']`. Beware that this latter expression can have performance issues on larger documents, since it has to search the entire input tree.